# Is there anyway I can run the same test case but with different values everytime?

Tags: ruby, jenkins, automation, cucumber

I have a single test case to test a particular scenario in a particular environment everyday, this is automatically done by a jenkins job.

```
Scenario Outline: Verify a user can book 
 Given I navigate to the "xxxxx" Page
 And I set the "Location" field with "<location>" value
 And I click on the "Search" button on "xxxxx" page
 Then I verify the "Results" page is displayed
 Examples:
  | location |
  |Boston    |
```

I need to internally have a list of 20 locations and everytime the test case is executed it changes the location some how, can be ramdon or in any order, but always changing.
I'm using cucumber, capybara and of course ruby

Thoughts please?

Comment: Why don't you write down all the 20 locations in examples list?

Comment: In that case it is not going to be a single test case anymore, it will be 10 or any number of locations that I would have

Comment: What specifically are you trying to test here? The presence of data?

Comment: Running test for each location once in 20 days expand your feedback time to 20 days. Do you really need such test?

Comment: @DaveNewton I need to test it is possible to complete a booking in different locations, but only 1 location each day.

Comment: @Pamela Understood, but my question is more like "Why do you need to test all the locations instead of making sure the location-specific data exists"? In other words, if the front end works for one location, why might it not work for the others?

Comment: aaa @DaveNewton it is just because location affects metrics, since it is a test, we do not want to affect metrics of like for example "most booked location" because of automated test. So we need to switch it everyday...

Comment: Your tests shouldn't affect production metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cucumber has a lot of limitations in terms of being used as a programming language. It's easier to do this kind of thing if you move it into a ruby file (cucumber files aren't ruby).

One option would be to make a single step that calls these other steps internally. Some people might say it's better to call *methods* rather than *steps* from inside other steps, but if you already have your cases written as steps than this will be quicker to do it this way, because you don't have to rewrite the code into methods. It is a good idea to write test code in methods and then call them from steps, by the way, rather than putting all the logic in the test cases.

Cucumber file:

```
Scenario Outline: Verify a user can book
  Given I navigate to the "xxxxx" Page
  Then the search bar works
```

Ruby file:

```
Then /the search bar works/ do
  locations = ["Boston", "Berkeley"].shuffle
  locations.each do |location|
    step %{I set the "Location" field with "#{location}" value}
    step %{I click on the "Search" button on "xxxxx" page}
    step %{I verify the "Results" page is displayed}
  end
end
```

Another reason this could be considered nonidiomatic is because it's packing too much into a single test case. However I'm not sure a good way to get around this other than simply copy-pasting the original step definitions in the cucumber file with different hard-coded values.

Comment: I don't find this particularly non-idiomatic given the nature of the test requirement (which I find suspect to begin with).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible

```
locations = ["Boston", ...]
day_of_the_month = Date.new(2001,2,3).mday
today_location = locations[(day_of_the_month - 1) % locations.count]
```

I use `- 1` in the third line since `#mday` returns integer from 1 to 31.

Comment: I tried it and changed the system date in order to be able to see it working, but it always select the first option in the list "Boston"

Comment: My example changes location each day, not month or year. Please look at my example https://repl.it/KTFm/0